# Bash string formatting

Tags: html, string, bash, formatting

Any idea how a can take a string like:

```
string=1,2,3,4,5
```

and using

```
number=4
```

put

```
<font color='red'><b></b></font>
```

around the corresponding number so the final product is:

```
newstring=1,2,3,<font color='red'><b>4</b></font>,5
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: does `number=4` refer to the exact match in `string` or to the fourth field of string? What if `string=a,b,c,d,e` and `number=4`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sed`:

```
result="$(sed "s|\($number\)|<font color='red'><b>\1</b></font>|" <<< "$string")"
```

The general form is: `sed s|search pattern|replace|` where `|` is some unique delimiter (normally you’d use `/` but that is already used in your string for other purposes). `\(…\)` is a *capture group* which captures the hit – in this case `4` and which can be used in the replace string via `\1`.

Comment: There will be a problem in case of `string=11,12,1,4` and `number=1`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "$string" | sed "s#\(,\|^\)\($number\)\(,\|\$\)#\\1<font color='red'><b>\\2</b></font>\\3#g"
```

Should work good enough in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

Pure bash?

```
string="1,2,3,4,5"
num=4

re="(^|.+,)($num)(,.+|$)"
if [[ "$string" =~ $re ]]
then
    echo -n "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    echo -n "<font>${BASH_REMATCH[2]}</font>"
    echo    "${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
else
    echo "$num doesn't match"
fi
```

will produce:

```
1,2,3,<font>4</font>,5
```

or perl:

```
echo '1,2,3,4,5' | num=4 perl -F, -lapE '$_=join ",",map{/\b$ENV{num}\b/? "<font>$_</font>":$_}@F'
```